# How to take user's form input and use it for event element?

Tags: javascript, events, button

How do I take the input in the forms, and apply them to the events "Name" and "TheirName" ?

Tried various codes from users that didn't work.

I'm trying to get the inputs of "name" and "theirname" to apply to the elements with blanks (____) when I click the Fill Names button

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("myname").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace("_____", "Name");
  document.getElementById("myname").innerHTML = res;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var str = document.getElementById("theirname").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace("_____", "Their Name");
  document.getElementById("theirname").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Name<br><input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Their Name<br><input type="text" name="theirname">
</form>
<p>This is a test for replacing "_____" with "Name" Name and "Their Name" for other name, for sentences with names and greetings.</p>
<p id="myname">Thank you for helping me with those shelves, by the way my name is _____. Would you like to help me with these boxes?</p>
<p id="theirname">There's customer outside who needs help bring a table inside. His name is _____. I'm going to go help him.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction();myFunction2();">Fill Names</button>
```

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I don't see any.

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epdhgLwz/

Comment: @j08691 you're right. i removed it

Answer (score 1):

When you do `str.replace("_____", "Name");` you're passing the literal string `Name` to the replace function when instead you want to get the value of the textbox. You can use `document.querySelector()` for that:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("myname").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace("_____", document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value);
  document.getElementById("myname").innerHTML = res;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var str = document.getElementById("theirname").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace("_____", document.querySelector('input[name="theirname"]').value);
  document.getElementById("theirname").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Name<br><input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>Their Name<br><input type="text" name="theirname">
</form>
<p>This is a test for replacing "_____" with "Name" Name and "Their Name" for other name, for sentences with names and greetings.</p>
<p id="myname">Thank you for helping me with those shelves, by the way my name is _____. Would you like to help me with these boxes?</p>
<p id="theirname">There's customer outside who needs help bring a table inside. His name is _____. I'm going to go help him.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction();myFunction2();">Fill Names</button>
```

Comment: I've never used document.querySelector(), but I suspect I'll be using it a lot now. Thank you @j08691

Comment: @TeaBadger You're welcome. Here's more info on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector